# Menu Views and Permissions

Tags: angularjs, laravel, menu, laravel-5

I am building an app, in my app i am want to have a page for an admin to manage user menu permissions.  What this means is that supposing i have the following menus:

```
Products
-Add
-Edit
-View
-Delete
```

And

```
 Users
    -Add
    -Edit
    -View
    -Delete
```

Now i want User A to be only able to see and go to:

```
Products:
-View
```

And

```
Users:
-View
```

The rest of the menu items will be invisible and inaccessible to User A.

What i have set out to do is to create tables for this in my database:

```
menu_groups
-id
-name
-description

menu_items
-id
-menu_group_id
-name
-state
-description
```

Menu groups table will hold all top-level menu items, in this case: products and users.

Menu items table will hold sub menu items: eg. Add, Edit, View, Delete

Now when the app loads i plan on checking user permissions then loading these menu items from the database, displaying and then caching them.  Obviously i will put a filter/middleware or whatever it's called on those routes on the server so no one can bypass it.

My question now is, is this the right way of doing it? In terms of security, efficiency etc.  Or is there another simple way of achieving this?

I use **mysql** for my database, **laravel-5** on my server and angularjs for client side.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with my application, it's a good solution. When a user tries to access a forbidden section on my website, laravel returns a 401 error which I catch automatically in my angular application by an interceptor.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 401) {
                //Redirect to login, show error etc.
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Okay so in your case all the menus show, just that when the users try to access a forbidden section it throws an error?

Comment: No I still hide the sections they can't access, I just added the interceptor to gracefully handle times when the server says the user is not authorized. You'll find that people bookmark restricted areas which breaks when the server says they are not authorized (until they login).

Comment: SO how do you hide those menu items then? Do you load them from the db like i want to do? Or do you have some other way you do it?

Comment: In laravel I added middleware to the routes I want to protect, and in angular I just used ng-hide or ng-show on my navigation items based on if the user is logged in, and if they have admin privileges. You're solution may be overly complex (unless you need to dynamically create the navigation such as users creating menu items).

Comment: Yes i know it is, the reason for that is that in my case the client may decide to set certain admin priveledges to a particular ser, therefore it might be possible for a user to add another user but not view users or edit users, something like that, so that's why i can't show/hide menu items based on roles or login status.